# SUMIF and OR function doesn't work

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I tried this function in Google sheets: `=SUMIF($D$3:D; OR(""; ">"&TODAY()); $B$3:B)`

Why is the result 0?
It shouldn't be :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

```
=SUMIF($D$3:D; ""; $B$3:B) + SUMIF($D$3:D; ">"&TODAY(); $B$3:B)
```

It is working but I guess, there is better solution.